# trouble with mysqli_free_results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having trouble using the `mysqli_free_result()` function. I am nesting queries and it seems when I free the results it stops the initial query from running its loop with the `while()` function. Am I using the `mysqli_free_result()` improperly? If I change the name of the 2nd query from `$results` to `$results2` it works fine. Seems there is an issue with the variables over writting, which is where I thought `mysqli_free_result()` would help but apparently not.

Here is a sample code similar to what I am trying to do.

```
<?php

// 1st query
$query = '';

// Run the 1st query
if( $results = mysqli_query( $db_connect, $query ) ) {
    while( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $results ) ) {

        // 2nd query
        $query = '';

        // Run the 2nd query
        if( $results = mysqli_query( $db_connect, $query ) ) {
            while( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $results ) ) {

            }
            mysqli_free_result( $results );
        }

    }
    mysqli_free_result( $results );
}

?>
```

Comment: It's a variable scope issue. PHP sets up a variable called $results when you do the first loop; and your second loop re-uses that same variable. If you want to do this, just use a different variable for the results of the second query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different variable name for your inner query.  Currently you are overwriting the `$results` on every run of the outer `while` loop.

```
<?php

// 1st query
$query = '';

// Run the 1st query
if( $results = mysqli_query( $db_connect, $query ) ) {
    while( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $results ) ) {

        // 2nd query
        $query = '';

        // Run the 2nd query
        if( $results_2 = mysqli_query( $db_connect, $query ) ) {
            while( $result_2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $results_2 ) ) {

            }
            mysqli_free_result( $results_2 );
        }

    }
    mysqli_free_result( $results );
}

?>
```

Update: As already pointed out on other comments and answers, `mysqli_stmt_free_result` **frees the memory for the supplied statement handle** as stated in the docs http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.free-result.php.  As @andrewsi points out, the issue is variable scoping issue.

Comment: In his question he has already said that it works when he names them differently, he wanted to know why.

Comment: @Robadob, I was adding the second sentence and I saw your comment.  His `$results` variable that's passed to `mysqli_fetch_assoc` in the outer `while` is the `results` from the inner `mysqli_query` after the first run.  Is this not true?

Comment: Yes, but your first sentence is telling him to try what he has already tried and said works. Wasn't answering the question, that's all.

Comment: Thanks vinodad, that's what I figured was happening and I would have to do to solve it.

Comment: Don't know why my questions always get voted down... Can never gain rep. Some fat troll always gotta vote others down.

Answer (score 1):

Free results frees up the handle, the results handle isn't a stack, you need to name your results handle's differently, unless you want them to overwrite.

"Frees the memory associated with the result." - [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php)